# How to left merge table_one with table_two based on latest month_year column?

Tags: python, pandas, string, datetime, machine-learning

table_one has distinct IDs. I want to left merge **table_one** on **table_two** based on **latest date in month_year** column. I did the following but didn't work.

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd

today = datetime.date.today()
first = today.replace(day=1)
lastMonth = first-datetime.timedelta(days=1)
latest_moyr =str(lastMonth.month)+ '_' + str(lastMonth.year)
```

```
final_df = pd.merge(left = table_one, right = table_two.loc[table_two['month_year']== latest_moyr], left_on = 'ID', right_on = 'ID', how = 'left')
```

**table_one**

| ID | Yrs |
| --- | --- |
| 1001 | 10 |
| 1002 | 2 |
| 1003 | 5 |

**table_two**

| ID | sum3 | month_year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 24.50 | 2_2013 |
| 1002 | 2.05 | 4_2013 |
| 1003 | 90.36 | 5_2013 |
| 1001 | 100 | 8_2013 |
| 1002 | 122 | 12_2014 |
| 1001 | 245 | 9_2018 |
| 1003 | 10.50 | 7_2011 |
| 1002 | 212 | 4_2018 |
| 1005 | 5.01 | 3_2014 |

I want to get like this

| ID | Yrs | sum3 | month_year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 10 | 245 | 9_2018 |
| 1002 | 2 | 212 | 4_2018 |
| 1003 | 5 | 90.36 | 5_2013 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to keep only last date per ID before merging. In order to do that, convert your `month_year` column into a proper `datetime64` then sort by date and drop duplicates for each ID.

```
df3 = df1.merge(
        df2.assign(dt=pd.to_datetime(df2['month_year'], format='%m_%Y'))
           .sort_values('dt').drop_duplicates('ID', keep='last').drop(columns='dt'),
        on='ID', how='left')
```

Output:

```
>>> df3
     ID  Yrs    sum3 month_year
0  1001   10  245.00     9_2018
1  1002    2  212.00     4_2018
2  1003    5   90.36     5_2013
```